# Edit NERDTree text using normal mode vim keybindings

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode, plugin-nerdtree

When using the "Add Childnode", "Move Node", "Copy Node", etc. options through the "m" menu, it opens up a text field to type in the name of the destination file.

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to edit this text using normal mode vim keybindings.  For example, using `b` to go backwards, or making a visual selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CTRL-F` from that input box to open the command-line window, which lets you use Normal mode commands and even access history to reuse a name you previously typed.

I suggest you read [`:help c_CTRL-F`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html?#c_CTRL-F) to see more details on how it works. Note that most of that help section talks about it in the context of the *command-line* (where you can type Ex commands), but most of that is also available for `input()`, which is what NERDTree uses to prompt for your input.

Some parts of it are not relevant in this context. For example, the `q:` command to open the command-line window from Normal mode. You can only access it with `CTRL-F` from the `input()` prompt. Otherwise, most of the information in that section (about navigating and closing the command-line window) is relevant.

Comment: This is perfect!  When I asked this question I was thinking about `q:` for NERDTree.  And that `help` page was also useful.  Didn't know about `q/` either.  Realized there's a lot of cool places to do `<C-f>` besides Nerd/Command mode.  Thank you for the above and beyond answer 